# Merging dictionaries and keeping unique values

Tags: python, json, group-by, mergeddictionaries

I am trying to merge a list of dictionaries in order to get a particular result.

This my list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA', 'id': 1, 'name': 'The Musical Hop'}, 
        {'city': 'New York', 'state': 'NY', 'id': 2, 'name': 'The Dueling Pianos Bar'}, 
        {'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA', 'id': 3, 'name': 'Park Square Live Music & Coffee'}]
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
[{
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "venues": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "The Musical Hop",
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Park Square Live Music & Coffee",
    }]
  }, {
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "venues": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "The Dueling Pianos Bar",
    }]
  }]
```

I tried this:

```
import operator
import itertools
outputList = []
for i,g in itertools.groupby(d,key= operator.itemgetter("city")):
    outputList.append(list(g))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to sort your data before applying [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools
import operator

result = []

for (city, state), group in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter('city')),
        key=operator.itemgetter('city', 'state')
):
    venues = [{'id': obj['id'], 'name': obj['name']} for obj in group]
    result.append(dict(
        city=city,
        state=state,
        venues=venues
    ))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'city': 'New York',
  'state': 'NY',
  'venues': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'The Dueling Pianos Bar'}]},
 {'city': 'San Francisco',
  'state': 'CA',
  'venues': [
      {'id': 1, 'name': 'The Musical Hop'},
      {'id': 3, 'name': 'Park Square Live Music & Coffee'}]
  }]
```

Comment: Hello funnydman. Thanks for this, but it isn't exactly what I want. I need to be able to  access the city key. E.g data['city']

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer